# Owl Carousel v2.2.1 Image on right TEXT on left sliding

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make slider text change with image but unable to do so. Kindly if anyone can help.

[image]

My code for this below:

```
<div style="background-color: #faf9f8;">
    <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
    <!-- blog author -->

    <!-- container end-->
```

```
    <div id="design" class="section md-padding bg-white">

        <!-- Container -->
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Row -->
            <div class="row" style="padding-top:10vh">

                <!-- why choose us content -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="section-header">
                        <h2 class="title">Latest News & Events</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>RELACOM SERVICES AS AN AUTHROZIED VEEAM RESELLER
```

Veeam Software recognizes Relacom Services (Pvt.) Limited as an authorized Veeam reseller in Pakistan. Contact us if you are looking for a backup and disaster recovery solution for your business

```
                </div>
                <!-- /why choose us content -->

                <!-- About slider -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="about-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                        <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="img/newsevents/0001.jpg" alt=""> -->
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/newsevents/0005.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/newsevents/0005.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/newsevents/0005.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /About slider -->

            </div>
            <!-- /Row -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Container -->

    </div>
    <!-- /Why Choose Us -->
```